# how to use GraphQLEnumType in my schema based on environment?

Tags: graphql

I have 2 app using the same graphQL for some feature. One app use some role, the second app use another set of role. This is the only difference in the interface with graphql.

SO I created an enum value resolver in my NestJS/GraphQL app.

```
export const UserType = new GraphQLEnumType({
  name: 'User',
  values: {
    USER: {
      value: 'USER',
    },
    VIEWER: {
      value: 'VIEWER',
    },
    ...(process.env.DOMAIN === 'admin'
      ? {
          ADMIN: {
            value: 'ADMIN',
          },
        }
      : null),
  },
});
```

Basically, I would like to generate a set of schema based on the environment.
so that when I do `npm run codegen` I can generate 2 different schema to that the FE can use based on the Environment.

the problem is, I do not understand how to use the above inside my `.graphql` queries

for exemple

```
type CreateSubUser {
  user: UserType!
  name: String!
}
```

this return

> unknown type "UserType"

Comment: You named it `User`, not `UserType`.

Comment: ah yes the post is unclear, I tried with both name tho, I just copied the last, and both don7t work

Comment: Are you actually adding the type into your schema? You didn't show the part of the code where you _use_ `UserType`.